# How prevent RegisterViewWithRegion adds new TabItems in PRISM?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, tabcontrol, region

OK

In my PRISM app I have 3 modules that each one have 3~6 views. in each module when `Initialize` method runs, after each `RegisterViewWithRegion` for each one of views, new `TabItem` appears in `Shell`'s `TabControl`. But i want to just add one `TabItem` at startup and each time user execute a `Command` and `Navigation` occurs, new `TabItem` appears.
Also user should be able to add or remove `TabItem`s.
What should i do? Implement a new `RegionAdapter` or what?

Here is my Shell `TabControl`:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" Grid.Column="2" Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionNames.MainRagionName}">
    <TabItem />
</TabControl>
```

and This is RegisterViewWithRegion:

```
var codingMainTreeView = _container.Resolve<Views.CodingMainTreeView>();
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRagionName, () => codingMainTreeView);

var vouchersMainView = _container.Resolve<Views.VouchersMainView>();
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRagionName, () => vouchersMainView);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from **Damian Cherubini** [Here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/387923).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.